# agregar elementos a un objeto javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este objeto:

```
let formdatax = [{
  tipo_reg: 'producto',
  producto : $("#producto").val(),
  categoria : categoria,
  tipo_categoria : tipo_categoria
}];
```

deseo agregarle estos datos: unidades,precio

sin reemplazar mi primer objeto

lo que e intentado:

```
  formdatax.push( [{
    unidades : $("#unidades").val(),
    precio_costo : $("#precio_costo").val(),
    precio_venta: $("#precio_venta").val()
  }]
```

con esto agrego estos elementos pero me los pone en un nuevo indice, y lo que yo deseo es continuar con el indice cero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado un bucle que lea las nuevas propiedades una a una y las asigne al objeto?

Comment: la verdad es que si lo e pensado pero supuse que habia una funcion mas directa

Comment: Pero hay algo que no cuadra... dices tengo este objeto, y pones en el código  un array de objetos...

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres acceder al índice cero y agregarle información podrías intentar con algo como esto

```js
let formdatax = [{
  tipo_reg: 'producto',
  producto : 'producto01',
  categoria : 'categoria',
  tipo_categoria : 'tipo_categoria'
}];

console.log("Arreglo original",formdatax);

//Agregamos infomacion

formdatax[0] = {
  ...formdatax[0],
  unidades : 10,
  precio_costo : 10.0,
  precio_venta: 12.0
};
 
 
console.log("Mismo arreglo con objeto modificado",formdatax);
```

En esta sección

```
formdatax[0] = {
   ...formdatax[0],
   unidades : 10,
   precio_costo : 10.0,
   precio_venta: 12.0
};
```

Generamos una copia del contenido del objeto con **...formdatax[0]** y le agregamos las llaves restantes "unidades, precio_costo, precio_venta".
Aunque parece que no necesitas un arreglo, podrías utilizar unicamente el objeto pero lo dejo a tu consideración :D

Suerte!

Comment: gracias amigo, pero el codigo me retorna los primeros elementos bien y las unidades,precio_costo y precio_venta en un indice[0] dentro del indice[0]

puedo acceder el producto (formdatax.producto) pero no a las unidades (formdatax.unidades)

Comment: {
    "0": {
        "unidades": "12",
        "precio_costo": "312",
        "precio_venta": "32131"
    },
    "tipo_reg": "producto",
    "producto": "dsadsa",
    "categoria": "1",
    "tipo_categoria": 1
}

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco más claro lo que necesitas?
Según yo ya sé cumplió los requerimientos de tu primer pregunta

Comment: si sabes que ya van a existir ese objeto porque no lo inicializas en 0/null?

Comment: @SaulMoreyra osea quiero todo en un objeto porque lo voy a mandar por un $.post por eso necesito en un array ordenado

Comment: @JackNavaRow como asi ?

Comment: let formdatax = [{
  tipo_reg: 'p',  producto : 'p',
  categoria : 'x',  tipo_categoria : 't',unidades:0,precio_costo:0,precio_venta0
}];, @IntruzO algo asi

Comment: @JackNavaRow a ya te entiendo, tu te refieres a que porque no lo pongo todo de una vez? es que el primer arreglo son datos "estaticos" y luego con un if condiciono los nuevos datos.